# Different results within the Nominatim Geocoder self-hosted version

Tags: apache, geocoding, self-hosting, nominatim

I have self-hosted Nominatim geocoding server on Ubuntu 22.04 following this post `https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/osm-nominatim-geocoding-server-ubuntu-22-04` and also setup a web server with Apache.

As you can see in the results below, fields like `name`, `addresstype` are present when queried via CLI but missing when queried via Apache web server. I would like to know why this is happening and how can this be rectified. TIA

FYI, I have also referred to this discussion `https://github.com/osm-search/Nominatim/discussions/3287` and other similar discussions but nothing is related to this issue.

```
nominatim search --query berlin --limit 1 --format json

[
    {
      "place_id": 131799146,
      "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://osm.org/copyright",
      "osm_type": "relation",
      "osm_id": 62422,
      "lat": "52.5170365",
      "lon": "13.3888599",
      "class": "boundary",
      "type": "administrative",
      "place_rank": 8,
      "importance": 0.7875390282491362,
      "addresstype": "city",
      "name": "Berlin",
      "display_name": "Berlin, Deutschland",
      "boundingbox": [
          "52.3382448",
          "52.6755087",
          "13.0883450",
          "13.7611609"
      ]
  }
]
```

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/nominatim/search?q=berlin&limit=1&format=json'

[
  {
    "place_id": 131799146,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "relation",
    "osm_id": 62422,
    "boundingbox": [
      "52.3382448",
      "52.6755087",
      "13.088345",
      "13.7611609"
    ],
    "lat": "52.5170365",
    "lon": "13.3888599",
    "display_name": "Berlin, Deutschland",
    "class": "boundary",
    "type": "administrative",
    "importance": 0.8875390282491362
  }
]
```

Status:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "message": "OK",
  "data_updated": "2024-02-19T00:56:55+00:00",
  "software_version": "4.3.2-0",
  "database_version": "4.3.2-0"
}
```